# How to keep XML tags but remove HTML tags

Tags: java, html, xml

I have an XML file that contains some HTML tags. I want to keep the XML tags but remove the HTML tags. For example in the following structure

```
<xml_tag_parent>
     <xml_tag_child>
       Some text here <p> some parag here </p>
     </xml_tag_child>
</xml_tag_parent>
```

I want to get:

```
<xml_tag_parent>
     <xml_tag_child>
       Some text here some parag here 
     </xml_tag_child>
</xml_tag_parent>
```

I don't know what are the xml tags in advance. 
Also Note that the HTML tags might be nested so I can't just get the value of the Node. For example in the following xml document:

```
<description id="description">
  <heading id="h-0001" level="1">CROSS REFERENCE</heading>
  <p id="p-0002" num="0001">The Paragraph </p>
  <claim attr="someAttr"> abcs </claim>
  <claim attr="2">
    <p> this is another paragraph <b>with some bold things</b> </p>
  </claim>
</description id="description">
```

I want to get:

```
<description id="description">
  CROSS REFERENCE The Paragraph
  <claim attr="someAttr"> abcs </claim>
  <claim attr="2">
    this is another paragraph with some bold things
  </claim>
</description id="description">
```

I could try and hard code all the HTML tags, find them, and remove them. For example I can look for < p > tag and replace it with empty string but this sounds not right, besides there are a lot of tags that I need to cover. Is there a library in Java or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Jericho** jar to achieve what you want.

It has the ability to extract only html tags and ignore all other tags, in line with what you want.

http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html

Comment: I have tried to use this like --> Source htmlSource = new Source("myhtml"); Segment htmlSeg = new Segment(htmlSource, 0, htmlSource.length()); Renderer htmlRend = new Renderer(htmlSeg); This will remove all tags including claims... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bahar Did it solve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup Library, which can help you in scrapping the html tags. A full tutorial can be obtained from [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). And the code that will work in scrapping your html tag is:

```
public static String htmltagremove(String html) {
     return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Comment: This code will remove the XML tags as well. I want to keep the XML ones but remove the HTML tags